invalid use of group by mariadb
I have the following code running in MariaDB
-- create
CREATE TABLE statistics (
  location text,
  type text,
  branch text,
  datetime date
);

-- insert
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('foo','a', 'a', '2024-01-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('foo','a', 'a','2024-02-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('foo','a', 'a','2024-03-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('foo','a', 'a','2024-04-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('foo','a', 'a','2024-05-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('bar','a', 'a','2024-01-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('bar','a', 'a','2024-02-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('bar','a', 'a','2024-03-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('bar','a', 'a','2024-04-01');
INSERT INTO statistics VALUES ('bar','a', 'a','2024-05-01');

-- fetch 
select
  location,
  count(s.type) as 'LocationTotal',
  StatisticsTotals.sum,
  monthname(datetime) as 'Month'
from  
    statistics s cross join
  ( select sum(count(type)) as sum from statistics ) as StatisticsTotals
where 
    branch like 'a'
group by 
    location,
  StatisticsTotals.sum,
  monthname(datetime)
order by 
    month(datetime)

I'm getting the error  ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 23: Invalid use of group function and I can't seem to figure out why.  Thank you

What do you expect the result of sum(count(type)) would be? The count() function will return a single value (since you did not use GROUP BY). The sum() of a single value will simply be the same value. So there's no use to nest an aggregate like that.

I think you should be ordering by monthname(datetime) rather than month(datetime) since month(datetime) is not in your select list.

Potential bug:  What happens when your data spills into the next year?
